# Updating/Upgrading Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Under Parallels 17 Mac M1 Chip Causes Crashes - Help?

Tags: mac, parallels

I have about 600MB of updates to download and install - but, in a previous attempt, after seeming to upgrade correctly - the OS refused to boot.

Again Mac M1 Chip Running Parallels 17 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Any help gratefully accepted.

rdbe

Comment: You're definitely missing a lot of updates if it reports as 20.04.2 because by now it should be .4. Try doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: OS refuses to boot? Try accessing the "recovery console", google it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your kind help!